# Works when run from Visual C++ but sometimes not standalone

Tags: c++, sfml, visual-c++-2010

**The actual question: what are the differences between running in Visual C++ 2010 (both release and debug mode) and standalone, excluding anything that couldn't cause the problem stated at the bottom of this post?**

I have a **very** specific problem with my program, so I am not going to post the code. If you would like to know details of the problem to gain some understanding, I post them at the bottom. Instead, I ask: what are the differences in running in visual c++ and standalone?

I am using Visual C++ 2010, and my program is using SFML 2.0. It runs fine in studio (I am calling it studio because it is easier to type), but when run standalone on *some computers only* a bug will occur within the program, to do with movement being delayed but other parts not. I cannot find any links between the computer specs of the users who test it and whether they work or not.

All dlls and such are included (at least, I think they are - the program runs fine, as detailed at the bottom -  maybe some users have some framework installed?). On my computer, it works all the time in studio but not standalone. On my netbook, it works, on my older computer, it doesn't. The only project settings I changed with vc++ directories and linker settings.

**Problem details:**
All the sounds sound slightly different and there is a possible high pitched background noise. Character movement, enemy movement and space bar delay which is supposed to be 0.5 seconds is increased to about 5 seconds but "generating pixels" (an aspect in the game with the arrow keys isn't.

I'm stressing again that it only happens on SOME COMPUTERS, mine included, but always works when run within studio. A number of people have tested the game, and some reported the problem and others different.

[**NOT THE MAIN POINT OF THE QUESTION BUT HERE IS AN EXTRA BIT**: If you are so willing to help me that you wish to look through the entire source code, it's here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53835113/EVERYTHING.zip [note: ignore the massive amount of bugs and memory leaks other than the problem described :P]]

**EDIT: THE POINT ISN'T THAT I WANT MY PROGRAM DEBUGGED! That is an optional extra. The question: what are the differences in running in visual c++ and standalone?**

**More edits: Found that the problem is due to the frame time not being correct. Not sure if this provides some insight.**

Thanks to anyone who tries to help me!

Comment: People are not likely to download a `zip` file.

Comment: Chances would be that your libraries(dll) are missing from the location where the exe is running, when standalone.

Comment: Either that or some sort of undefined behavior is happening.

Comment: We are not here to debug your code for you; SO is the place to ask if you have a _specific_ question.

Comment: It seems that people are missing the point of the question - I meant to add the source as an optional extra, editing...

Comment: @Charles - as a matter of interest, why not? Also: edited for clarification

Comment: @Pig Head, because firstly, people are busy and likely do not want to be bothered with taking the extra steps to download and extract a compressed file.  Secondly, `zip` files can contain viruses, and it's not a good idea to download them from the Internet unless the source is absolutely trusted.

Comment: @Dumb - what kind of dlls would cause the problem described? Wouldn't dlls just mean it breaks/not breaks, not run un studion and on some computers but not others?

Comment: I've had programs produce different output depending on whether they're run in debug or release mode, perhaps that's what's happening here?

Comment: @Pig Head, the problem is that there's not enough information to say anything for sure, so it's impossible to provide a good answer to this question.  A C++ program which works on one computer but doesn't on another can happen for all sorts of reasons - the biggest one being undefined behavior from a programmer error, or non-deterministic behavior as a result of programmer error (threading bugs) or different inputs from different environments.

Comment: Are you linking statically to the CRT? If not, do the other computers have the proper VC++ CRT redistributable installed? If not, they need to.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia - Is there anything else I can provide? I tried to give as much detail as possible. Also, I don't know what the CRT is, but presumably no. BDoes studio use it automatically then?

Comment: The CRT is the C Run-Time library, and is installed automatically with Visual Studio -- thus you will have it on any computer with VS installed, but it is not necessarily installed otherwise. You need to install the CRT redistributable on all other machines running your application unless you statically link to the CRT instead.

Comment: @ildjarn Except it doesn't work on my computer! It works when run in studio on my computer only, standalone is has the same problem

Comment: @PigHead: My guess would be that you do not properly initialize buffers and variables. When run from MSVC, the debugger will initialize these to a known value, when started standalone they can contain anything...

Comment: Thanks. Your solutions provided me with fixes for other bugs, and also I found the solution to this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetFrameTime() in SFML was removed in a recent version because it returns the time since last frame rather than the time since last update. As a result, the it may return 0.